# why slicing in go works for index 1 more than the length but not further

Tags: go, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s:= []int{1,2}
    fmt.Println(s[0:]) // this is expected
    fmt.Println(s[1:]) // this is expected
    fmt.Println(s[2:]) // this wondering why i didn't recieve slice bounds out of range error
    fmt.Println(s[3:]) // here i recieve the error
}
```

Can some one explain why s[2:] returns empty slice [] but s[3:] errors out. i thought s[2:] should error out too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [The Go Programming Language Specifications](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

> For arrays or strings, **the indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= len(a), otherwise they are out of range**. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions

`s[3:]` gives an error because your `low` index (which is 3) is greater than `len(s)` (which is 2) and therefore `out of range`

> The indices low and high select which elements of operand a appear in the result. The result has indices starting at 0 and **length equal to high - low**.

`s[2:]` gives you an empty slice because your `low` index (which is 2) and your `high` index (which defaults to `2` by golang spec), which results in a slice with a length of `0` (`high - low`)

Answer (score 3):

```
0     1     2    n-1    n
|_____|_____|_..._|_____|
 s[0]  s[1]        s[n-1]
```

I found this explanation from a golang book. Above is the indices, and below is the elements.

We could see that n is also a valid index when getting subslices, and this could explain why `s[a:b]={s[a], s[a+1], ... , s[b-1]}`, and `s[n:]=s[n:n]={}`